# PHP can't find path while HTML can

Tags: php

I'm still a bit new to PHP and stumbled across a weird error I can't fix.
I have different util PHP files for different purposes, such as getting user data or basic util functions.

But I can't figure out why PHP does sometimes not find the path when using the `require` function.

In particular this example:

```
print '<a href="/api/connection.php">Huh</a>';

ob_start();
require "/api/connection.php";
ob_end_clean();
```

HTML shows a working link redirecting to the page, but PHP still can't find the connection file. 

Here is my file tree: 
[image: Never gonna give you up]

So why is that and how can I fix it? Does PHP have another way of linking files or is it something else?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP paths are relative to the root of the filesystem, not the document root. Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the latter.

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/api/connection.php";
```